# What is the significance of (int*) in this program?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, casting

I wrote two programs which prints out the variable the pointer `p` points to:

First program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){

    int *p;
    int a=5, q;

    p=&a;

    q=*p;
    printf("%d", q);

}
```

Second program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int a=5;
    int*p;

    p= (int*)&a;

    printf("%d", *p);

return 0;
}
```

My question:

Both the programs print the value of `a` which is `5`. However, the second program uses `p=(int*)&a;` instead of just `p=&a;`. Could someone please tell me the significance of `(int*)` casting here?

Comment: `(int*)` is a cast. It is useless since `&a` is already of type `int*`.

Comment: It's a useless cast.

Comment: Note that `(int*)` isn't *just* a useless cast, it's also an extra point of maintenance and dangerous: if someone changes from `int a = 5;` to say `short a = 5;`, the program with `(int*)` could then be compiled and executed with undefined behaviour, but if the C-style cast isn't used you'll get a compiler error until you update `int* p;` to a type corresponding to `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting is a way for a programmer to tell the computer that, even though the computer thinks something is one type, we want to treat it as another type.

But here the cast is of no use as here a is an integer and thus address of a will need no cast here for integer pointer.

Comment: oh...okay. Then, if 'a' is a float but I want to treat it like an int.....then the (int*) would be required?

Comment: @Eliza: that's right, but dangerous: on some platforms they don't occupy the same number of bytes in memory, some integer values may be invalid "trap" representations when stored read into a floating point register, and you'd want to make sure you understood strict aliasing rules thoroughly first.

Answer (score 3):

There is no significance, rather, this cast is superfluous and not required.

In your code, `a` is of type `int`, `p` is of type `int *`. Hence,

```
 p= (int*)&a;
```

and

```
p= &a;
```

are same and the second one here is recommended.

Answer (score 2):

It's useless.

`a` is an `int`, so `&a` is already a pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Useless use of `type casting`. It's like,

```
int a = (int) 10 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is typecasting ,to tell the compiler that the value that is assigned to the pointer p that is &a is an integer type(int) but there it is of no use as &a return the address that is assigned to the variable a and it is always an integer.